# Cross-DB LIKE function

Tags: sql, sql-like, ansi-sql

I have to perform this query

```
select * from mytable where number like '%11%
```

where number is a numeric field. I found the solution for Postgres doing this:

```
select * from mytable where CAST(number as text) like '%11%
```

But if i try to execute this query in Oracle or MySQL, i have an error. I need a

cross-db instruction that do this.

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried?

Comment: But why do you want to do LIKE on a number?

Comment: I have to verify if an order number (that is a numeric field) contains a specific number

Comment: Most DBMSes support a version of a MODULO operator, combined with integer division this can be used to extract digits. Can you show some actual data and how you want to process it?

Comment: @Domenico . . . Please provide examples of what you are looking for.  `LIKE` works on numeric values.  And you can convert numbers to strings.

Comment: `number_column::text LIKE '%123%'`

Comment: I have to perform this query

select * from mytable where number like '%11%
where number is a numeric field. I found the solution for Postgres doing this:

select * from mytable where CAST(number as text) like '%11%'
But if i try to execute this query in Oracle or MySQL, i have an error. I need a

cross-db instruction that do this.

Comment: `where CAST(number as varchar) like '%11%` should work with Oracle and Postgres. No Idea about MySQL

Comment: Exactly, it works on Oracle and Postgres but not in MySQL!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIKE` operator like this:

```
CAST(intField AS varchar(50)) LIKE '%' + CAST(intValue AS varchar(50)) + '%'
```

Other solutions like using modulo need a recursive query based on the length of your `intField` and your `intValue` like this example:

```
intValue = 234  &  max_length_intField = 6

(intField Between 234000 AND 234999) OR
(FLOOR(intField / 10) Between 23400 AND 23499) OR
(FLOOR(intField / 100) Between 2340 AND 2349) OR
(FLOOR(intField / 1000) = 234)
```

Comment: @Domenico As I know in some db you need to use `||` instead of `+` or using `CONCAT` function ;).

Comment: `||` is the concatenation operator defined by the SQL standard.